# Using MiniO with Docker and .NET not interacting with API

Tags: .net, docker, minio

I have a basic `docker-compose.yml` file that creates a MiniO container for me to interact with, for development purposes:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  storage:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    command: server --console-address ":9001" /data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - storage-data:/data
    environment:
      - MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin
      - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=superstrongpassword
    healthcheck:
      test: timeout 5s bash -c ':> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/9000' || exit 1
      interval: 5s
      retries: 1
      start_period: 5s
      timeout: 5s

volumes:
  storage-data:
```

I am then configuring MiniO using their .NET Nuget Package:

```
services.AddMinio("admin", "superstrongpassword");
```

I am then using the MiniO Client to create a bucket:

```
public class MinioStorageService(IMinioClient minioClient) : IStorageService
{
    public async Task<string> CreateContainerAsync()
    {
        var containerName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower();
        var makeBucketArguments = new MakeBucketArgs().WithBucket(containerName);
        await minioClient.MakeBucketAsync(makeBucketArguments);

        return containerName;
    }
}
```

Registering this in the service container:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStorageService, MinioStorageService>();
```

and then finally, inside a controller I am doing the following:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("/hello")]
public class HelloWorldController(IStorageService storageService) : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CreateContainerAsync()
   {
      var bucketId = await storageService.CreateContainerAsync();

      return Ok(bucketId);
   }
}
```

I am getting the new GUID (bucket name) returned to the browser when this is completed and no exceptions are being thrown, however, upon inspecting the browser (localhost:9001) I can see that no buckets have been created.

Please note that the .NET Application is running on the host machine, and is not within a Docker container itself.

I have tried the following:

- Alternating between Docker images `minio/minio` & `quay.io/minio/minio`
- Changing ports from 9000 to 9001
- Tried to access via access keys, added admin in case it was a policy.
- Creating the client manually without dependency injection
- Turning off `.WithSSL(false)`
- Manually setting the endpoint.

Unfortunately, none of these seem to work. The only thing I can see in the logs is a warning of:

> - The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.

However, I don't believe that to be a problem.

The health check also seems to be performing ok.

EDIT:

I navigated to the docker terminal for this container ran the following commands:

`mc alias set testing http://127.0.0.1:9000 admin superstrongpassword` 
`mc mb testing/test-bucket1`

Doing this, I can confirm that the bucket was successfully created with the credentials provided.

Further investigation:

I have now plugged my code to use the `play.min.io` demo. I can confirm that this works and creates the bucket as expected, so it is likely an access / Docker issue.